# Can't make SD Card as internal storage

Tags: internal-storage, internal-sd

I wanted to make my Samsung  as internal. I went to **Storage and USB** and selected *Erase and Format* option to make it as internal.
After formatting it to about 40% [image: this] message popped up. I selected OK and then opted to move on. Then I selected **Move Now** when it asked me my permission to move my data from internal to this. But then just after that [image: this] message popped up. Now right after I press OK it goes back to the option to **Move Now** and it all goes in a loop.
Also SD Card is always shown corrupted after the process.

Please help me. I have restarted my phone multiple times now and even tried to format it first in my computer and then go through the process, but I got the same results.

Comment: Use the SD-card in an USB-SD-Card-reader in a PC and format & overwrite it completely. If that works the card is OK and you should be able to format it in your phone.

Comment: @Robert did that. I even used a different SD card but the same error popped up. obviously now it said that _this transient SD card is too slow..._

Comment: @Shadow_Sphynx - were you able to find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: @Dan no, sadly i was not able to do it.